# Why don't Chinese people use 又紅又專 any more?

Tags: phrase, terminology

[又紅又專](https://www.omgchinese.com/dictionary/chinese/%E5%8F%88%E7%B4%85%E5%8F%88%E5%B0%88) means being both socialist-minded and professionally competent and this phrase used to be popular in China. Since the People's Republic of China is still a socialist country, why don't people use it anymore?

Comment: “ . . . is still a socialist country” omg, it’s **sarcastic** lah, sahib 

Comment: @水巷孑蠻, I thought it is one of the Four Cardinal Principles (四項基本原則) which the communist party will never change.

Comment: Quote:- "...why don't people use it anymore?"They do, but with a slight modification to 又绿又專 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The color "Red" symbolizes "Blood", "Revolution". It has become the symbol of a Communist Region since the start of the Russian revolution, then it was imitated by the majority of the Communist countries, including China, whose country shared similar experiences politically and had followed the Russian's led.

However, after its relationship with the Soviet Union had severed and after Mao's death, the Chinese Communist Party no longer think the rigid communist doctrine is the feasible way for the party's survival, and in turn, now it fears the potential of internal unrest, due to widespread poverty and unsatisfaction, that could lead to another "revolution" and overthrow the ruling party. Thus, it has dropped many old political slogans/symbols that encourage people against the ruler and unfair treatment.

Now, China emphasizes improving the living standard and increasing/opening private wealth ownership for its citizen (more green - US dollar) rather than encouraging its citizen to "revolt" (thinking red and devoted to it) except for its party members, who, until now and foreseeable future, still hold the power to rule, to control, and to stir the direction of the country politically through the iron fist and the communist ideology.

Answer (score 2):

That phrase mostly used during Cultural Revolution period. It makes people thinking of Cultural Revolution. Since Cultural Revolution ended many years ago, people mostly won't use it unless joking about something.

Answer (score -1):

因为那个词语很老套了，应该是台湾或香港朋友曾经这么说过吧，现在中国新青年会讲：党坚势盛

Comment: You need to learn the history of your own country. "又红又专是中共中央于1961年9月发布的《高教六十条》中之词汇，“红”是指具有无产阶级的世界观，“专”是指专业知识及技能。此词汇代表政治与业务的关系。此外，中共中央并发出通知，要求干部又红又专，实现政治与技术的合一".  https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%8F%88%E7%B4%85%E5%8F%88%E5%B0%88